# Display ESRI MapService (WMTS) with EPSG:28992 coordinate system in Leaflet web map with OpenStreetMap base layer

Tags: leaflet, wmts, proj4js, netherlands

ESRI MapService https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/nSZVuSZjHpEZZbRo/arcgis/rest/services/Historische_tijdreis_1870/MapServer have EPSG:28992 coordinate system.
In QGIS I can add this layer via WMTS https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/nSZVuSZjHpEZZbRo/arcgis/rest/services/Historische_tijdreis_1870/MapServer/WMTS  (layer: Historische_tijdreis_1870, format: image/jpgpng, tileset: default028mm, crs: EPSG:28992)
Is there any way display this layer directly on Leaflet web map with OpenStreetMap base layer (or I need reproject tiles using MapProxy)?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ewzjdmLf/1/

Comment: Leaflet supports only one CRS per map. If you want different CRS for different layers, you'll have to use OpenLayers.

Comment: solved in OpenLayers https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/337848/display-esri-mapservice-wmts-with-epsg28992-coordinate-system-in-openlayers-w#337860